# how to add Runtime ImageViews into linearlayout

Tags: android

i am getting runtime imageviews,how can i add that imageviews into one single Linear Layout.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ImageView imageView= new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF00FF);

    //linearLayout=LinearLayout+imageView;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams Iv=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(Iv);

    linearLayout.addView(imageView);
    setContentView(linearLayout,vp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ImageView imSex = new ImageView(context);
addView(imSex,linearLayout);
```

Comment: @user2243468, run time means are you downloading from Internet?

Comment: then you can just make **URI** of particular image path and set to image view. will solve your problem.

Comment: my problem is how can accumulate(adding multiple imageviews) imageview's in single linearlayout